# How to slow down onDrawGizmos

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to C#/Unity and looking for a way to slow down onDrawGizmos.
Currently everything works great.

```
void OnDrawGizmos() {
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position, new Vector3(gridWorldSize.x,1,gridWorldSize.y));
    if (grid != null) {
        foreach (Node n in grid) {
            Gizmos.color = (n.passable)?Color.white:Color.red;
            Gizmos.DrawCube(n.worldPosition, Vector3.one * (nodeDiameter-.1f));
            Gizmos.color = (n.searched)?Color.red:Color.white;
            Gizmos.DrawCube(n.worldPosition, Vector3.one * (nodeDiameter-.1f));
            if (path != null) {
                if (path.Contains(n)) {
                    Gizmos.color = Color.yellow; 
                    Gizmos.DrawCube(n.worldPosition, Vector3.one * (nodeDiameter-0.1f));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Except that it is all drawn basically instantly in Unity. I would like to show the order each drawcube comes in as it is a pathfinding demo.

- I have tried putting onDrawGizmo in IEnumerator and using
  WaitSeconds. But onDrawGizmos seems not to work at all this way.
- I have tried Task.Delay inside the foreach loop, but this does not
  work and Unity just hangs or becomes unresponsive.
- Finally I tried Thread.Sleep and this had a similar effect.

Any pointer in the right direction to help me slow down onDrawGizmos would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Start with `grid` empty and add objects to it as you want them to show up.

Comment: so what code is producing/filling the grid? I guess you would rather do the "slow done" there and let `OnDrawGizmos` just be the display of the actual current state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not be the best solution, but you can use a counter to execute the code conditionally, like this:

```
int execCounter = 0;
void OnDrawGizmos() {
    execCounter++;
    if (execCounter > 300) {
        excecCounter = 0;
        //.....your code
    }
}
```

If what you want to slow down is the `foreach` speed instead the whole `OnDrawGizmos()` code, you can use the same approach inside the `foreach`. You can play with the harcodded value `300` which I just put randomly until it fits with your desired speed.

Comment: Problem with that might be that `OnDrawGizmos` is called quite often in Unity and a bit hard to control the actual duration  ^^

Comment: yeah, that what the counter is for, while the `counter++` is being done, the code in the `OndrawGizmos()` wont run, so you can "skip" or jump calls. If its called to often, make the counter bigger. As said, not the most elegant solution, but can be a start to help the OP

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!!! I appreciate it!